# Determining the type of database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a new Pc which was having both **Sql server2008 and sql server2008 R2**, I am not able to recognise that which instance name belongs to Sql server2008 and which to Sql server2008R2.
How can i come to know it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will work for you.

```
Select  @@VERSION as [Server Version],@@ServerName [Instance Name]
```